# Найти значение в object

Tags: javascript, объекты, search

Задача такая: нужно "вернуть родословную" в 2 объектах т.е
есть 2 объекта `obj1` и `obj2` и их свойства:

```
obj1["Женщинам"] = 'кросовки,топы';  
obj1["Мужчинам"] = 'шорты,майки';
obj2["кросовки"] = 'adidas,puma';
obj2["топы"] = '...';
...
```

теперь допустим нужно найти `puma` и функция должна вернуть `кросовки -> Женщинам`

Comment: Может, лучше переделать структуру объектов, если есть возможность?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko к сожалению нет. Объекты используются не только для этого

Comment: Очень странное задание... Что вы пробовали сделать? Есть какие-то наработки, идеи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функцию `search` передаете в масиве сколько угодно обьектов по которым будет осуществлятся поиск и значение от которогу нужно построить цепочку. Обьекты нужно передавать в порядке в которм должен осужествляться поиск. На выходе получите масив с ключами где были найдены вхождения.

```js
const obj1 = {};
const obj2 = {};

obj1["Женщинам"] = 'кросовки,топы';  
obj1["Мужчинам"] = 'шорты,майки';
obj2["кросовки"] = 'adidas,puma';

const search = (arrObj, target) => arrObj.reduce(
    (prev, curr, index) => [
        ...prev,
        Object
          .keys(curr)
          .find(key => curr[key].includes(prev[index]))
    ],
    [target]
)

window.document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = search([obj2, obj1], "puma").join('->')
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

пс: перед тем как использовать в продакшене нужно допилить обработку исключительных ситуаций ;)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так))

```js
let obj1 = {
  "Женщинам": 'кросовки,топы',
  "Мужчинам": 'шорты,майки'
};

let obj2 = {
  "кросовки": 'adidas,puma',
  "топы": 'nike,guchi',
  "шорты": 'nike'
};

$('#click_me').click(function() {
  let name = $('#company').val();
  let keys2 = [];
  $.each(obj2, function( key, value ) {
    if (value.indexOf(name) !== -1) {
      keys2.push(key);
    }
  });
  
  $.each(keys2, function( key2, value2 ) {
    $.each(obj1, function( key1, value1 ) {
      if (value1.indexOf(value2) !== -1) {
        console.log(value2 + ' -> ' + key1);
      }
    });
  });
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Введите фирму" type="text" id="company"></input>
<button id="click_me">Click ME</button>
```

Comment: Чуть-чуть не соотвествует условию. Должно же быть `кросовки -> Женщинам`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Поправил ))))) ))))

Comment: Но ведь все равно выходят и `топы -> Женщинам`. А раз у нас кроссовки, то нужны только `кросовки -> Женщинам`! Или я не понял задание о_О

Comment: Я просто немного усовершенствовал задание, ведь могут быть разные вещи одной фирмы. Поэтому Пума стоит для двух категорий. let obj2 = {
  "кросовки": 'adidas,puma',
  "топы": 'nike,puma',
  "шорты": 'nike'
}; Если поменять значение свойства "топы", то вадасть только одно значение.

Comment: Неужели вопрошающий где-то написал, что он хочет, чтобы это было сделано через jQuery? Пожалуйста, если вас об этом не просят, то не пишите через jQuery.